# Controller ViewBag.data in _Laoyut.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag, asp.net-mvc-layout

I have a **Controller** and I want to send **ViewBag** data in **Controller** at _Layout.cshtml.

**Example:**

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.username Blog Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome, @ViewBag.username</h1>
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

MainController.cs

```
public class MainController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Session["user"] != null)
        {
            var user = (tbl_user)HttpContext.Session["user"];
            ViewBag.username = "serife";
            ViewBag.testdata = "hellooo!";
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
<label>Index Page</label>
<br/>
<label>@ViewBag.testdata</label>
<br/>
<label>@ViewBag.username</label>
```

Result:

## Welcome,

Index Page
hellooo!
serife

Comment: Does you `Index` view use that layout? If so, then `user.username` must be `null` or an empty string.

Comment: No, MainController have got a View page and `user.username` not empty.

Comment: It must be, otherwise it would display the value of `username`. To test this add `<div>@ViewBag.username</div>` in the `Index.cshtml` view as well.

Comment: I'm sorry. What is the your solition?

Comment: There is no 'solution'. The code you have shown works fine if `user.username` has a valid value. What was the output of adding `<div>@ViewBag.username</div>` in the `Index.cshtml` view?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure that's the exact code?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. Do you konow **_Layout.cshtml** before to run than **Index.cshtml**.

Comment: It makes no difference. The code you have shown works fine.

Comment: This is solved the problem. Thanks Stephen..